# do...while stopping 2 months early?

Tags: javascript

```
var date = new Date(); 
do {
    var sel = date.toString();
    document.write(sel + "<br>");
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
   } while(date.getDate() != 2 && date.getMonth() != 2)
```

Why does this stop on Jan 1..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/PYXeu/.

Jan 1rst have getDate == 2.

**Edit:** If you want this go to 2.02 check the code in http://jsfiddle.net/PYXeu/1/

Comment: In your code `while` will stop when `getMonth() == 2`, or `getDate() == 2`. In my code it stops when both `getMonth()==1` and `getDate() == 3`. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: Ohh interesting. I appreciate the link!

Comment: May I also point out for further readers that this above is a PROPER answer, as it details a WHY it is correct. Not just stating "You're wrong I'm right." (As such I wish I could vote it up twice)

Answer (score 3):

Because at Jan 2, the first condition returns false and the execution stops. I assume you want the script to continue all the way to Feb 2, in which case your condition should look like this:

```
} while(date.getDate() != 2 || date.getMonth() != 1)
// Stops when day is 2 and month is 1 (February)
```

Or:

```
} while(!(date.getDate() == 2 && date.getMonth() != 1))
```

Both mean the same thing. Note that months are zero indexed so February is 1. This results in a output like this:

```
...
Fri Jan 28 2011 14:57:00 GMT+0200
Sat Jan 29 2011 14:57:00 GMT+0200
Sun Jan 30 2011 14:57:00 GMT+0200
Mon Jan 31 2011 14:57:00 GMT+0200
Tue Feb 01 2011 14:57:00 GMT+0200
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/MF7bR/

Comment: The first one should stop on getDate == 2 OR getMonth == 1. Which doesn't make sense. The second one stops on Jan 1.

Comment: @Meke, could you describe what you are trying to do? And the examples I provided are valid and working and mean the exactly the same, both stop at Feb 1. Take a look at the URL I posted.

Comment: @Meke, you should test the code before making a comment like this, @Tatu Ulmanen is right on the first one, it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second iteration `.getDate` is 2. The while can't execute. You need to increase it to 3 if you want it to stop once it has completed 2.

It also wouldn't hurt if you were more explicit in your code about what you're adding to the date.

Comment: And why can't it execute if getDate is 2 when getMonth is 0?

Comment: Because that condition evaluates to false which drops out of the while. getDate != 2 --> false. false && true == false.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit March or 2. day of month, your loop won't be executed anymore. This is because months start from 0, so January is 0 and December is 11.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the month starts at index 0 for January.  You will need to adjust your loop accordingly for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe months start at 0, so on the 1st of January date.getMonth() == 0, which != 2.

Comment: So it shouldn't stop on Jan 1... The condition is true.

Comment: So it is! I must have misthought the question. Thanks.